# matplotlib RGB image different cmap?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

Is there a way to change the colormap of an RGB image in matplotlib from hsv to say twilight?

If I have an array that is x,y,3 from 0 to 255, it gives a normal RGB image. Is this somehow changable to say colorscheme from the twilight cmap? As a way to make the picture work for colorblind people.

Comment: A matplotlib colormap maps scalars to color. An RGB image contains vectors (3 values, one for each channel), so it's not clear how you imagine to represent a 3 channel image with a colormap. Maybe you can clarify?

Comment: There is no prebuilt way to do this.  But you could do aminimization to figure out what index each RGB tripple has in HSV and then map the indices to twilight.

Comment: ... and thereby neglecting the s and v channel? This will surely make the image *less* readable for colorblind people.

Comment: Looks like you need to research actual algorithms for color correction. See https://gsocsarjak.wordpress.com/2017/08/23/image-processing-library-to-ease-differentiation-of-colors-for-colorblind-people/ or https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318307402_Image_Color_Transformation_for_Deuteranopia_Patients_using_Daltonization